# How to get tamplateData into javascript files in Docpad?

Tags: javascript, templates, preprocessor, npm, docpad

Is there a [DocPad](http://docpad.org/) plugin that could pre-process the js files and use [templateData](http://docpad.org/docs/template-data) variables and helpers to get configuration values available?

I've tried [Hogan](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-hogan/), I can get the variables but not call the helpers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ECO plugin for Docpad](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-eco/) I could achieve what I was looking for.

I can get both values and call helpers from docpad templateData.

Answer (score 0):

Any templating language will work here are a few examples and their matching templateData variables:

#### Docpad.coffee

/docpad.coffee

```
docpadConfig = {
    templateData:
        site:
            url: "http://www.example.com"
}
```

#### Eco:

/src/documents/index.html.eco

```
<p>My site is <%= @site.url %></p>
```

#### CoffeeScript:

/src/documents/index.html.coffee

```
p "My site is " + @site.url
```

Or within a script file:

/src/documents/scripts/scripts.js.coffee

```
console.log( @site.url )
```

/out/scripts/script.js

```
console.log("http://www.example.com");
```

#### [Hogan](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-hogan):

/src/documents/index.html.hogan

```
<p>My site is {{@site.url}}</p>
```

#### [Jade](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-jade):

/src/documents/index.html.jade

```
p My site is #{site.url}
```

Comment: I should add that if you're trying to pre-process a javascript file it would make the most sense to use Coffeescript which will have access to those variables.

I'll update the post to reflect this option.

Comment: The CoffeeScript example is not working. Any alternative Solutions for this?